# image resize in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, product-view

Right now when I upload an image into a Magento product at 920 x 1380 and I go to the Product display page it displays  the image at 500 x 750 it scales down the image in proportion

The end Image size I want on the Product display page is 390 x 585 this is also in proportion to the 920 x 1380

How can I do this?

If found that i needed to edit the media.phtml file but when I do that the image size is to small to trigger the zoom feature. So now how do I get the image size on the product page to be 390 x 585 and have the zoom feature? The Image size I am loading into magento is big enought for the zoom feature. The image is 920 x 1380

Answer (score 1):

Please check code which is below for Product image resizeing.

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(390, 585);
```

Comment: is this in the media.phtml   app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view                                         I added this in that code file `code`<img id="image-main"
             class="gallery-image visible"
      src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(true)->resize(390, 585); ?>`code`

Comment: Yup if you need to resize the image in product view page then you need add the code in media.phtml

Comment: I did that but when I did that the zoom feature no longer worked.

Comment: what you mean by zoom feature?

Comment: if you mouse over the image you will see it zooms in on a section https://magento.digitalmarauders.com/index.php/jewlery/banana.html

Comment: But when I add the resize code into the media.phtml the mouse over zoom is gone

Comment: am I editing the right code in the right file?

Comment: Please find the below added code, Zoom feature is missing because for product-image div zoom-available class is missing, add the zoom-available class as in screen shot you will get image zoomer. <div class="product-image product-image-zoom zoom-available">

Comment: I added that into the code but zoom still does not work . `<div class="product-image product-image-zoom zoom-available">
    <div class="product-image-gallery">
        <img id="image-main"
             class="gallery-image visible"
      src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(true)->resize(390, 585); ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />`

Comment: https://magento.digitalmarauders.com/index.php/jewlery/banana.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for product images in list.phtml file(app/design/frontend/[current package]/[current theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml)

Code:

> `<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($width, $height); ?>`